# Why are quotes needed in Number(('' + num)…)?

Tags: javascript

Why are the quotes needed after Number? How would this be written using parseInt instead?

```
function squareDigits(num){
  return Number(('' + num).split('').map(function (val) {
    return val * val;
  }).join(''));
}
```

Comment: They’re needed to make `num` a string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a string for later splitting the digits.

This could be done by adding an empty string or by using `toString()` method, which is implemend not only for `Number` and `String` object.

- [`Number#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)
- [`String#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toString)

```js
function squareDigits(num) {
    return Number(
        ('' + num)                // convert to string
            .split('')            // split works only with string
            .map(function(val) {
                return val * val;
            })
            .join(''));
}

console.log(squareDigits(27));
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the brackets it would be

```
'' + num.split('')
```

and that would try to execute `.split` before the string concatenation, therefore it wont work as that does not exist on a number. With the brackets it gets concatenated to a string first *and then* split is called on it.

Answer (score 0):

The function works as the following:

Let's assume that we passed 234 to `squareDigits` function, it will convert that number to a string (by `''+num` statement) and then split that string (using `.split('')`) into individual numbers in an array (`['2', '3', '4']`),and for each number (they still strings actually) we will multiply it by itself (by mapping the array), the multiplication will work because we use auto-casting. SO the result would be `[4, 9, 16]`
Finally, we will join the array to form a string (`4916`) and then casting it to number (using `Number` constructor).

The function using `parseInt` wouldn't be any different:

```
function squareDigits(num) {
    return parseInt(('' + num).split('').map(function(val) {
        return val * val;
    }).join(''));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing bad about is your code It is fine.

> Why are the quotes needed after Number

quotes  not needed for `Number` It is essential for split function

```
34.split(''); // will throw error

(''+34).split(''); //will work fine
```

I am adding alternative for this It is just a alternative as I already mentioned your code is looking good.

```js
function squareDigits(num){
  return parseInt(num.toString().split('').map(function (val) {
    return val * val;
  }).join(''));
}

console.log(squareDigits("25"));
console.log(squareDigits(25));
```